# Regular Expression matching a certain number in the text

Tags: c#, regex, list, foreach, match

I have a file that looks like this:

```
STUFF   STUFF       **X**     **Y**  STUFF STUFF
J6      INT-00113G  227.905    5.994  180  SOIC8    
J3      INT-00113G  227.905 -203.244  180  SOIC8     
U13     EXCLUDES    -42.210  181.294  180  QFP128    
U3      IC-00276G     5.135  198.644  90   BGA48     
U12     IC-00270G  -123.610 -201.594  0    SOP8      
J1      INT-00112G  269.665  179.894  180  SOIC16    
J2      INT-00112G  269.665  198.144  180  SOIC16
```

And I need to grab the **3rd column** and the **4th column** seperately and store them into a list in C#.

---

I am currently matching the **3rd and 4th column together** using:

```
        var xyResult = new List<string>();
        var mainResult = new List<string>();

        foreach (var mainLine in fileList)
            mainResult.Add(string.Join(" ", mainLine));

        foreach (var xyLine in mainResult)
        {
            Match xyRegex = Regex.Match(xyLine, @"[\d]+\.[\d]+\s+[\d]+\.[\d]+");

            if (xyRegex.Success)
            {
                xyResult.Add(string.Join(" ", xyRegex));
            }
        }

        List<string> finalXYResult = xyResult.ToList();

        foreach (var line in finalXYResult)
            displayXYRichTextBox.AppendText(line + "\n");
```

---

Right now I am storing the regex matching both **X and Y** into *one* list. I would like to store the two column values seperate. *So*, one list for **X** and one list for **Y**.

---

***QUESTION:***

- What regex can I use to match the 3rd column of numbers and store it in ***"X"*** and also *(or seperately using another regex)* match the 4th column of numbers and store it in ***"Y"***?

***EDIT:***

```
    private void calculateXAndYPlacementTwo()
    {
        // Reads the lines in the file to format.
        var fileReader = File.OpenText(filePath + "\\Calculating X,Y File.txt");

        // Creates a list for the lines to be stored in.
        var fileList = new List<string>();

        // Adds each line in the file to the list.
        while (true)
        {
            var line = fileReader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;

            fileList.Add(line);
        }

        // Creates new lists to hold certain matches for each list.
        var xyResult = new List<string>();
        var mainResult = new List<string>();
        var xResult = new List<string>();
        var yResult = new List<string>();

        foreach (var mainLine in fileList)
            mainResult.Add(string.Join(" ", mainLine));

        mainResult.ForEach(xyLine =>
        {
            Match xyRegex = Regex.Match(xyLine, @"(?<x>-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(?<y>-?\d+\.\d+)");
            if (xyRegex.Success)
            {
                String xValue = xyRegex.Groups["x"].Value;
                String yValue = xyRegex.Groups["y"].Value;

                xyResult.Add(String.Join(" ", new[]{ xValue, yValue }));

                foreach (var line in xValue)
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(line + "\n");

                foreach (var line in yValue)
                    richTextBox2.AppendText(line + "\n");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make things easier I've named the groups, but the following should work:

```
(?<x>-?\d+\.\d+)\s+(?<y>-?\d+\.\d+)
```

Please note that this requires both the 3rd & 4th column to have decimal numbers (I don't do any checking to accept either whole or decimal numbers, but if necessary, this can be added).

Note the above [has been tested](http://regexr.com?2uaad) to work.

**Summary**

Basically we use the capture you had, but extend it using capture groups (the parenthesis). I also use named groups (the `?<x>` and `?<y>` at the start of the group) so you can reference the values found using `xyRegex.Groups["x"]` and `xyRegex.Groups["y"]`, respectively.

I also found your capture failed when numbers appeared with negative values, so I added an optional negative symbol (`-?`) to the pattern to account for that.

So, broken down, here is the statement:

```
(?<x>              # Begin capture group "x"
  -?                 # allow a negative symbol 0 or 1 time
  \d+                # allow 1+ numbers
  \.                 # allow a single decimal
  \d+                # allow decimal numbers 1+ times
)                  # end capture group "x"
\s+                # allow white space between the number sets
(?<y>              # Begin capture group "y"
  -?                 # \
  \d+                #  | - same as above
  \.                 #  |
  \d+                # /
)                  # End capture group "y"
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works? How could I implement this into my current code?.. Also, there is not an actual line that labels it `STUFF, STUFF, ***X***, ***Y***, STUFF, STUFF`. There is just the data and not 'labels'

Comment: Thanks. I tried your demo but instead of a sample string I am using a file. And also instead of writing to the console I am outputting to 2 richtextboxes. My problem now seems to be properly outputting to the richtextboxes. Replacing your `Console.WriteLine()` with `richTextBox1.AppendText(xValue + "\n"); richTextBox2.AppendText(yValue + "\n");` does not seem to be 'showing' any values in the RTBs. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Colton: How about [this version](http://www.ideone.com/gZSEi)? -- or **[BETTER YET](http://www.ideone.com/OU8WR)** I broke it down to formats you're already using, including iterating over a string list. You may not want to cast to doubles either, and may just want to keep them in string format before pushing the values to the RTB.

Comment: I seem to be having some trouble with this haha

Comment: @Colton: trouble in what regard? Either explain here, or post an update to your question.

Comment: I have been messing around with your *linked* code above that you have posted and cannot seem to output the matched data out to richtextboxes (one for x, one for y).

Comment: I am updating my code above.. (I was messing with Chadwick's code since I was struggling with yours)

Comment: I Updated the code above in the **EDIT** section to incorporate your code.. however it still is not working properly.. ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use regex groups, and then get the individual elements from the result of the match.

```
foreach (var xyLine in mainResult) {
    //PLACEMENT TWO Regex
    Match xyRegex = Regex.Match(xyLine, @"([\d]+\.[\d]+)\s+([\d]+\.[\d]+)");

    if (xyRegex.Success) {
        xResult.Add(xyRegex.Groups[1].Value);
        yResult.Add(xyRegex.Groups[2].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: It errors, stating that the `.Groups` cannot be used like a method